# SQL (Server) error converting varchar to float. Text + amount

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, sqldatatypes, converters

This code works and outputs nicely

Code:

```
select (sum(SchemeAccount.AdoptionAmount)- convert(varchar,Scheme.Acquisition,103)) [£ Output]
```

Output:

[image]

I now want the amount to be preceded by the word 'Variance'

So I try:

```
 select 'variance'+  (sum(SchemeAccount.AdoptionAmount)- convert(varchar,Scheme.Acquisition,103)) [£ Output]
```

But then get:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to float.
```

What I want is 'Variance £73,102,500' or at least 'Variance 73102500'

I have tried a lot of CAST and convert(varchar,col,103) functions and have either not been successful or got 'Variance 73e105' or something like that.

If more info is needed on my current data types, I can try to acertain.

Comment: Tag with the database you are using, which certainly seems to be SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `concat()`.  I assume you intend:

```
select concat('variance',
              convert(decimal(20, 4), sum(SchemeAccount.AdoptionAmount)),
              '-',
              convert(varchar(255), Scheme.Acquisition, 103)
             ) as [£ Output]
```

Comment: Thanks G. But my output is now 'Variance 7.31025e+007-0' 
Can you help me get a proper number? It's like £73m. Massive variance.

Comment: @DasalKalubowila . . . (1) You can convert to a decimal/numeric.  (2) You should not be storing amounts as floating point numbers.